# error after excuting python file to exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, user-interface, youtube-dl

Hi can you help me convert The python file to EXE file using pyinstaller I created an app for download video from youtube with GUI and I want to convert it to exe and when I convert it by pyinstaller I open the app and it gives me [This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBb2Q.png)

and when I run it in pycharm or in visual studio The code runs ok And no problem And when I Excute it And open the app it give that Error Can you help me please to solve this error. My Thanks

```
    from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from pafy import new
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.win=Tk()
        self.win.title("Youtube Video Downloader")
        self.win.configure(bg="#ed071e")
        self.win.geometry ("600x120")

        self.win.resizable (False, False)

        self.label=StringVar()
        self.coin = tk.StringVar ()
        self.coin2=tk.Label (self.win,text=" Enter URL   :",bg="#E8D579")
        self.coin2.grid (row=1,
                         column=0,
                         pady=5,
                         padx=5)
        self.win5=StringVar()
        self.link=Entry(self.win,textvariable=self.win5,width=55)
        self.link.grid (row=1,
                            column=1,
                            pady=5,
                            padx=5,
                            columnspan=2)

        destination_label = Label (self.win,
                                   text="Distination   :",
                                   bg="#E8D579")
        destination_label.grid(row=2,
                                column=0,
                                pady=5,
                                padx=5)
        self.dairc=StringVar()
        self.destinationText = Entry (self.win,
                                      width=40,
                                      textvariable=self.dairc)
        self.destinationText.grid(row=2,
                               column=1,
                               pady=5,
                               padx=5)

        self.browse=Button (self.win,
                           text="Browse",
                           command=self.browse,
                           width=10,
                           bg="#05E8E0")

        self.browse.grid (row=2,
                   column=2,
                   pady=1,
                   padx=1)



        self.down=Button (self.win,
                             text="Download",
                             command=self.download,
                             width=20,
                             bg="#05E8E0")
        self.down.grid(row=3,
                     column=1,
                     pady=3,
                     padx=3)



        self.win.mainloop()

    def browse(self):
        download_Directory = filedialog.askdirectory (initialdir="YOUR DIRECTORY PATH")
        download_Path = StringVar ()
        download_Path.set (download_Directory)
        self.download_Folder = download_Path.get ()
        self.dairc.set(self.download_Folder)


    def download(self):

        self.win7 = tk.StringVar ()
        load=tk.Label (self.win,textvariable=self.win7,bg="#ed071e")
        load.grid(row=4,
                         column=1,
                         pady=3,
                         padx=3)
        link=self.win5.get()
        video = new(link)
        dl = video.getbest()
        dl.download(self.download_Folder)
        messagebox.showinfo ("Done",
                                 "video saved in \n"
                                 +self.download_Folder)
        self.win7.set("Done")



        self.down=Button (self.win,
                                 text="Download another video ",
                                 command=self.delete,
                                 width=10,
                                 bg="#05E8E0")
        self.down.grid(row=4,
                         column=2,
                         pady=3,
                         padx=3)
        self.win.mainloop()

    def delete(self):
        self.win5.set("")
        self.dairc.set("")
        self.win7.set("")
        self.down.destroy()


App()
```

Comment: Try this: `pyinstaller --hidden-import=youtube_dl downloadvideo.py`

Comment: I try it (same problem)